# Using optionals effectively in VueTS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

Being rather new still to coding, especially in Vue, I wonder what reasonable ways there are in Vue / Typescript to declare non-existent values depending on the context.

Pre-thoughts:

- Whenever we bind variables to component templates, they must not be `undefined` at any time - or the responsiveness breaks apparently
- With that in mind, I started to use as a default declaration `typeA | null` more often
- Dealing with interfaces, data structure and the actual database, I'm a bit lost sometimes how I should write them. Let's look at a simple example:

*user-settings.ts*

```
// For each new user a new object of type `UserSettings` is created, e.g. in the cloud in `onAuthCreate`

// option A
export interface UserSettings {
    analyticsEnabled: boolean
    personalDataRequestedAt?: number
    personalDataDownloadLink?: string
    userId: string
}

// option B
export interface UserSettings {
    analyticsEnabled: boolean
    personalDataRequestedAt: number | null 
    personalDataDownloadLink: string | null
    userId: string
}

// option C
export interface UserSettings {
    analyticsEnabled: boolean
    personalDataRequestedAt: number // starting with 0
    personalDataDownloadLink: string // starting with ''
    userId: string
}
```

- **A** feels very flexible and probably closest to what feels intuitive; but I guess I would need to repopulate all properties that are `undefined` with `null` locally before transmitting them to my components in order to protect template-binding (or is there another way / something I miss?)
- Following **B** I will have this kind of declaration almost anywhere in my interfaces - it feels very explicit and requires the properties in every instance (which may be a positive aspect as much as it could be a negative aspect?)
- **C** feels more like what's used in a UI component to setup default values

I wonder what the most "vue-like" approach is that goes well together with typescript and general coding habits.

Answer (score 1):

> C feels more like what's used in a UI component to setup default values

C is out of the question. Here it is again for reference:

```
export interface UserSettings {
    analyticsEnabled: false
    personalDataRequestedAt: 0
    personalDataDownloadLink: ''
    userId: string
}
```

In this you are saying e.g. `analyticsEnabled` is *always* false. This is *not* the same as saying its the default value.

> In case of B I will have this kind of declaration almost anywhere in my interfaces - but it feels very explicit

I prefer B. Explicit is good, explicit is *correct*

Comment: Sorry there was obviously a mistake in C the way the interface was declared. Now it should be correct.

Comment: So would you not use optional values at all in combination with Vue (while it is more common e.g. in React)? That doesn't feel right either, no? Even the Vue library contains optionals all over the place... But how would you deal with the template binding efficiently then?